# Could a charge with more than 3 types be self consistent?

Tags: internal-consistency, physics, alternate-reality, quantum

I know [color charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_charge) has three types: red, green, and blue.  There is also just one type of electric charge, with there being negative and positive electric charges.

I was thinking of a universe, in which there is a charge with a number of types that is greater than 3, known as A Charge.  Equal amounts of all types of A Charge cancel each other out, to produce a system with 0 A Charge.  Also all the types of A Charge are equivalent.  In this universe relativity Special Relativity, and General Relativity apply.  Also the Uncertainty Principle applies.

Could A Charge be self consistent?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to say: you state there is just one type of electric charge and then you list two, and then what is a color charge?

Comment: Color charge is a real concept in physics and relates to quarks, which are elementary particles.  I added a link to Wikipedia's page on the subject.  Note that quarks have *both* an electric charge and a color "charge".

Comment: I think you missed out anti-red, anti-green and anti-blue...

Comment: I enjoyed this question and the HDEs answer but I don't think it should be on Worldbuilding SE. Physics SE would make more sense. I just don't see any context (book, RPG, computer game) in which it would ever be remotely important for your setting whether or not the forces and physical laws of your universe would make sense to some people in a different universe (ours) with different rules. You are the worldbuilder - it works however you say. Real life can only effect how plausible people find it, and stuff people mostly don't know (symmetry groups) won't impact what they find plausible.

Comment: There are some questions like this that make me imagine a god-like entity making a new universe as a homework assignment.  Like he is asking this well done simulation for advice for how to produce his version.

Comment: @Dast 100% of the questions on worldbuilding can be answered by "you're the worldbuilder-- it works however you say." But that's a boring answer, so generally people like to furnish fun and interesting explanations instead-- yet for whatever reason, hard sci fi questions like this almost always attract a bunch of responses like yours. I agree that if you want to engage a wider audience, this is way too specific. But this isn't writing stack exchange, or RPG stack exchange. If a person wants to construct a world for just themselves to ponder, that seems like a perfectly valid use of this site.

Comment: @elduderino Thank you for the great answer. I still think physics stack exchange would have been more appropriate but meh.

Comment: @Dast No problem! I don't think Physics SE would fit for a question like this-- in my experience they tend to close speculative questions about different universes. But even more than that, imo one of the biggest strengths of worldbuilding is the diversity of questions. Personally, I'm not interested in fantasy settings, but I don't think fantasy questions should be moved off the site-- I just don't read them. I like that worldbuilding has something to offer for everyone and I think we should be careful not to exclude certain types of questions just because they don't personally intrigue us.

Comment: @Dast Physics An important difference between world building physics and real world physics is that deductive reasoning is most useful for world building physics, while inductive reasoning is most useful for real world physics. In world building physics you start with first principles, then derive the laws of physics from those first principles, then figure out the implications of those physical laws.  In real world physics you start with observations and experiments, then find a model that best describes those observations, then find first principles that describe the model.

Comment: @AndersGustafson I half agree. When I worldbuild I often go the same direction as real physics does. I start with "my setting has flying machines built by low tech people", then progress too "what needs to be different about the laws of physics in my world for this technology to be easy?" (Maybe gravity is weak, or buoyant materials common, or the gravitational mass of solids falls in proportion to the brightness of the light field they are exposed too.). Then yes I would go the direction you describe (eg. if light makes things light the desert probably gets awesome sandstorms by day).

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it could be consistent.

For each of the fundamental forces, we have a certain conserved quantity, [which we refer to as a *charge*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_(physics)). The [converse of a result called Noether's theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24596/56299) tells us that in most cases, a conservation law leads to [something called a *symmetry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_(physics)#Continuous_symmetries)$^{\dagger}$, and each symmetry is associated with a mathematical structure called a symmetry group. If we were given a charge, then by studying the symmetry group associated with it, we could learn about the quantum field theoretic interactions that arise from it, and vice versa.

The fundamental forces have the following symmetry groups, respectively:

- **Electromagnetism:** The very simple unitary group $\text{U}(1)$
- **Strong nuclear force:** The more complicated special unitary group $\text{SU}(3)$
- **Weak nuclear force:** The special unitary group $\text{SU}(2)$

We can then learn something about the charges associated with the force and the bosons mediating its interactions. The number of distinct fundamental charges is given by the dimensions of the [irreducible representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_representation) of the symmetry group, and the number of bosons is given by the number of [generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group) of the group.$^{\ddagger}$ $\text{SU}(2)$ has three [*generators*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group), and so we have three gauge bosons associated with the weak nuclear force: the $W^+$, $W^-$ and $Z$ bosons. Its representations are two-dimensional, and there are two charges associated with the weak force.

You've simply given us a new conservation law (which at a glance looks "nice" enough for us to be able to apply the converse of Noether's theorem), and therefore a new symmetry group. There's nothing prohibiting us from considering higher-dimensional groups (and as pregunton mentioned, we can go beyond unitary and special unitary groups) that would in turn be associated with new types of charge, giving us new bosons to play around with.

---

$^{\dagger}$ Noether's theorem itself says that any continuous symmetry has a corresponding conservation law.

$^{\ddagger}$ In particular, the group $\text{SU}(n)$ has $n^2-1$ generators and therefore $n^2-1$ bosons. The group $\text{U}(n)$ has $n^2$ generators and $n^2$ bosons.

Comment: Since Electromagnetism is $\text{U}(1)$ would a $\text{U}(n)$ force work, and if so how would an $\text{U}(n)$ force be different from a $\text{SU}(n)$ force?  Also seeing as $1^2-1=0$ would this mean that a $\text{SU}(1)$ charge wouldn't work?  Would a charge that is neither $\text{U}(n)$ nor $\text{SU}(n)$ work?

Comment: @AndersGustafson $\text{U}(n)$ is the same as $\text{SU}(n)\times\text{U}(1)$ (up to a finite factor), so the number of bosons would be $n^2$ (the $n^2-1$ from $\text{SU}(n)$ and an extra "photon"). The group $\text{SU}(1)$ is trivial, so there is no $\text{SU}(1)$-charge. There are many other groups you can work with, the complete list is roughly $\text{SU}(n), \text{SO}(n), \text{Sp}(n), U(1), G_2, F_4, E_6, E_7, E_8$ and products of these (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_simple_Lie_groups)).

Comment: @pregunton Where I see the dimension Column, is that what indicates the number of force carrying bosons there would be?

Comment: @AndersGustafson Yep, that's correct! The group's dimension corresponds to the number of bosons there would be. The number of charges is more difficult to determine, you have to look at the dimensions of something called irreducible representations. For example $G_2$ is itself 14-dimensional and has a 7-dimensional smallest irreducible representation, so there would be 7 fundamental charges and 14 force carriers (in this particular case charges still combine in groups of three however, due to complicated reasons).

Comment: @AndersGustafson I'm seconding everything pregunton said - we're not restricted to unitary groups. I just restricted myself to talking about them for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @pregunton I'm confused.  What do you mean when you say that charges combine in groups of 3 for $\text{G2}$?

Comment: @AndersGustafson It means that even though there are 7 charges, there are certain groups of 3 charges that 'sum to zero', so you can still form 3-component neutral particles (if you want more details, take [this graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane) where each dot is a charge. The charges that sum to zero are the ones that lie on the same line/circle). The reason is complicated and has to do with the fact that the smallest irreducible representation preserves an invariant 3-form. This is different from $\text{SU}(n)$, where the only way to cancel the charges is to have all of them.

Comment: @pregunton Would it be possible to have a charge for any finite geometry?  Also is there a $G_n$ or only a $G_2$?

Comment: @AndersGustafson No, the only possible ones are essentially what I listed above. There is only a $G_2$ (it's a so-called exceptional symmetry group because it's not part of an infinite series).

Comment: @pregunton I was also wondering for the ones that don't have the number in parentheses, but instead have the number in subscripts or superscripts, how do I tell the number of charges?  Also are there any besides $U(1)$, in which there are no charged force carriers?

Comment: @AndersGustafson As I said you have to look for the dimensions of irreducible representations (there should be tables online). And no, the only groups with uncharged carriers (also called Abelian groups) are essentially products $U(1)\times U(1)\times\ldots\times U(1)$. Anyways, if you are interested about all this you should learn about representation theory. There are whole books about this and it would take too long to explain everything in a comment thread.